# android sorting arraylist of "Like"

Tags: android, sorting, parse-platform, collections

I would like to implement a "Like" function for my app.

There are different stories in sequence for my app, each with an unique key. When user presses the "Like" button, it will upload the String arraylist of user's "liked key" to Parse.com, e.g. as follows:

```
User A's favorite: {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13};
User B's favorite: {1, 3, 4, 5, 10};
User C's favorite: {1, 2, 11, 14, 20};
User D's favorite: {1, 2, 12, 19};
```

I am planning to retrieve and sort as follows:

```
    arr_conso.clear();      
    for (ParseObject parse_table : ob)
    {
        List<String> favorite_array = (ArrayList<String>) parse_table.get("fav_list");              
        arr_conso.addAll(favorite_array);                
    }  

    counting = new HashSet<String>(arr_conso);
```

where `arr_conso` will append all users' favorite story key, and `counting` will extract from `arr_conso` for unique question key.

### Question:

1. How could I further sort the story key in descending order of its frequency in an efficient manner, with output as follows

   `Story 1: 4
   Story 2: 3
   Story 3: 2
   Story 5: 2
   Story 7: 1...`
2. Would there be max number of items in arraylist, e.g. `arr_conso` in the above case?
3. How should normally database of "Like" be managed? Here it is to store "Like" per user, should it be better to store "Like" by question? Would there be any examples or library for "Like" and "Comment" management?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to sort the like list is to add a new 'likes' number column on your stories table.In that column you are going to save the number of likes each story has.

So when a user likes a story that column will be increased by 1 and when a user unlikes a story it will be decreased by 1.
In this way is much easier for you to retrieve the like list in any order you like.

About the "Like" database, storing per question is a more efficient way to manage and retrieve the informations you need.

Comment: I understand the benefit of storing the number of likes / who likes the story if the likes are stored per story level.  However,  i could not figure out the infrastructure / stability when there are multiple users pressing like to the same question at the same time.  When an user to like,  the like column has to added by 1 or add the user name,  so as dislike.  The second user may retrieve during the process of the first user and retrieve a shorter one before the first one pressed like.  How could this be handled?

Comment: I use this style in my own apps. In order to avoid conflicts, when a user presses the like button i fetch from the database the likes number and then i increase or decrease it. This way, even if multiple users press the like button at the same time, there will be no conflicts and parse will handle the requests processes.